# M-way search tree using binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

I was asked this in an Interview:

How can one implement a M-way search tree using a binary tree?
I could not think of any approach then, looked up for the same dint find anything relevant.

Edit: As a clarification I'd like to add, the real question is to make a M-way tree using a binary tree data structure, like a queue can be implemented using 2 stacks.

Any ideas, approaches are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make every node in the tree store a pointer to it's first child and a pointer to it's next sibling then you have a binary tree representation of your m-ary tree.